# How to exclude one match from regex that otherwise is match for another rule?

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a redirect rule, but I don't know how to exclude one specific case

I need to redirect everything that has "images" in url to a url that start with "/images", but "/images" should not be matched.

This matches anything that start with "images"

```
^(images)[/](.*)$/i
```

This excludes "/images"

```
 ^[^\/](images)[/](.*)$/i
```

This matches anything that has more segments before "/images"

```
 ^.*(images)[/](.*)$/i
```

How do I combine these three so that these are matched

> /asdf/images/sadf.png
>
> images/asdf.png

but this one is not

> /images/sadf.png

Comment: Well, a lookahead solution looks the best, like [`^(?!/images(?:/|$)).*(images)/(.*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/NjeS5h/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`/^(?!\/images).*images\/.*$/`

This will do the following:
`^` from the start of line
`(?!\/images)` don't match if the first thing is "/images"
`.*` match any characters (optional) - could limit this if certain characters can't exist in your route
`images\/` matches any instance of "images/" that does not contradict the earlier assertion

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
^(?!/images\b).*\bimages\b.*
```

Using `\b` (word boundaries) stops matching input like `unimagestrate`.

Comment: this is definitely more sturdy than my answer +1 for putting thought in beyond OP's test cases. This will, however, still match something like "blah/other-images/blah"